# Is this upper bound on the smallest eigenvalue of $A+B$ correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Working on a long, tedious proof, and just want to check myself.

Given two square symmetric real matrices $A$ and $B$, the claim is that
$$\lambda_{\min}\left(A + B\right) \le \lambda_{\max}\left(A\right) + \lambda_{\min}\left(B\right),$$ where $\lambda_{\min}$ and $\lambda_{\max}$ are the smallest and the largest eigenvalues, respectively. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you can show it using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient